# Tokenize with delimiters

Tags: java, regex, tokenize, delimiter

I'm trying to delimit a source code to tokens where I want delimiters as `\\s|+;,{}[]` to be tokenized. But I somehow fail at this, any advice ?

```
public void tokenize() {
         StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(this.sourceCode, "\\s+|[;{}\\[\\]]", true);

        int counter = 0;

        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
          String token= (String) st.nextElement();
          tokenizedCode.put(counter, token.trim());
          counter++;
        }
}
```

EDIT: Note: that delimiter does not tokenize correct what i expect

I want `int a=10;` to be tokenized in `int,a,=,10`

Comment: Euhm where are you failing ? What doesn't work ?

Comment: If delimiter does not work which I highlighted what do you think?

Comment: For the new example you provided, you could maybe use [`\\s+|[][;{}]|(?==)|(?<==)`](http://regex101.com/r/bN0oT2). Note that tokenizing source code is a difficult task, I mean what if I had `;` or `=` in a string like `System.out.print("This is an equal sign =. Nothing special");`

Comment: Helped a bit, ty :D i do realize, bu it is supposed to become a mini compiler at some point meanwhile need to fix this part :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of the `StringTokenizer` class doesn't take a regex as parameter, so you would do this instead:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(this.sourceCode, " ;{}[]=", true);
```

**Note that `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.** Ex:

```
String[] result = this.sourceCode.split("\\s+|[;{}\\[\\]]");
for (String str : result) {
     System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: I do need to keep the delimiters :s

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of the constructor makes it return the delimiters also.

Comment: **I want int a=10; to be tokenized in int,a,=,10**

The ; is not present in the expected result